# Parallelize a Random Forest prediction

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, random-forest, joblib

I am trying to code a specific version of a Random Forest and to make both the training and the prediction computations parallel using joblib Parallel.

Suppose that I have written a TreeEstimator with `.fit` and `.predict` methods. The `.fit` method outputs the construction of the tree and the `.predict` method outputs an array of value. Then my code looks like this.

```
class RandomForest()
    def __init__():
        ...
    
  
    def fit(self, dataset):
        self.roots = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(delayed(tree.fit)(dataset) 
                                                  for tree in self.trees)


    def predict(self, dataset):
        preds = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(delayed(self.parallel_pred)(row) 
                                                     for row in dataset)
        return np.array(preds)
        

    def parallel_pred(self, row):
        pred = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(delayed(tree.predict_row)(self.roots[i],row) 
                                           for i,tree in enumerate(self.trees))
        return pred
```

The `.fit` methods works just fine: all my CPUs are used up to a good percentage. However, the `.predict` methods seems to mainly do the computations on only one CPU and few others CPUs are sometimes used at ~2-5% at most. I have also tried doing the following: one loop `for` over all the rows of the dataset and applying the `.parallel_pred` method on each row of the dataset. It does not work, i.e runs mostly on one CPU. I have also tried doing a
`Parallel()(delayed(tree_preds)(row) for row in dataset)` with the `tree_preds` function being a `for` loop over all trees to get each prediction one by one but it still runs on mostly one CPU.

To sum up, I want to do one loop over my test dataset and one loop over my tree estimators to get for each row of the dataset all the predictions of all trees. I would like to make this in a *parallelizable* way.

I use Python 3.+ with Ubuntu 20.+)

Comment: Finally it can compute in a decent time (few seconds for 5000 samples and 200 trees) :
- In the Tree `.predict` method, we use np.apply_along_axis to benefit from numpy factorization, it returns a np.array.
- Then the Forest `.predict` method uses `Parallel(backend="threading")(delayed(tree.predict) for tree in self.trees)`.
For a reason that I ignore, "loky" and "multiprocessing" backends have a hard time so the CPU ressources are still used in a suboptimal way. Still it is satisfying for my application.